# How to return error from OFBiz SECA service

Tags: java, ofbiz

I am using a `seca` to validate a field's value from the database. If the field value doesn't match with required string it will return error with some string using `ServiceUtil.returnError(String);`

When using `ServiceUtil.returnError("Some error messages.")`. OFBiz show the error message

```
The Following Errors Occurred:

Error calling event: org.ofbiz.webapp.event.EventHandlerException: Service invocation error (No transaction manager or invalid status)
```

I want to show only the error message string which I pass in the `ServiceUtil.returnError` method. How should I achieve that? Am I missing something? The sample code is below:

Service eca:

```
<eca service="createProduct" event="commit">
    <action mode="sync" service="checkProduct"/>
</eca>
```

service_validator:

```
<service name="checkProduct" engine="java" location="mypackage.validation.ValidationServices"
         invoke="checkProduct" auth="true">
        <description></description>
        <attribute name="productId" mode="IN" type="String"/>
</service>
```

ValidationServices.java:

```
public static Map<String, Object> checkProduct(DispatchContext dctx, Map<String, ?> context) {
    String productId = (String) context.get("productId");
    if (productId.equals("Not my product")); {
        ServiceUtil.returnError("Not my product");
    }
    ServiceUtil.returnSuccess();
}
```

**Note:** If I changed event of SECA to in-validate it will return the message and append with the transaction rollback exception message and then the full string showed it in the screen. How can I show only the message that has been return from the service?

Answer (score 0):

1. First make sure that the database is configured properly in your IDE.
2. Check the usernames and password for the database are all correct.
3. Make sure that the queries you have written in your code are all correct.
4. This sure you mentioned above are configured properly.
5. Update all the dependencies and libraries of your project.
6. Restart your servers and restart your IDE .

Then re-run your project. It should run.

Comment: Thanks for reply. The code is work correctly, even it logged the error message properly. Log message `Message: Error in Service [checkProduct]: Not my product.`  But in the screen it only showing the above message not the given one.

Comment: You trying refreshing your web browser web page. When you see this error message. How it should work

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't understand what you are saying. The screen is only showing the exception message of what TransactionManager throw. Not the error message I am returning from service. The expected result should be it only show the message (in screen) which I return from the service,